Can we chain the lwc components? Suppose we have 3 components and we need to move from one to another
Suppose we have 3 components and we need to call them from one to another. When a button is clicked on S1 then we can move to S2. There is a button on S2 when pressed it will move us to the last S3 screen. I tried working with NavigationMixin but it is not a good option I think so. What other ways can we try in this scenario. Attaching screenshot for reference.
Thanks in advance.


Depending on where you would use the components, I would consider writing them as separate components for flow use, and have them reactive or capable of automating flow navigation, potentially using a decision variable that gets populated by the components.

In your example image, you have a fourth box that contains the other three. This is the container that we would use to orchestrate the components S1, S2, and S3. Each component would then communicate that a new component should be displayed.
<template>
  <!-- this is the parent component -->
  <c-s1 lwc:if={step1} onnext={goToStep2}></c-s1>
  <c-s2 lwc:if={step2} onprevious={goToStep1} onnext={goToStep3}></c-s2>
  <c-s3 lwc:if={step3} onprevious={goToStep2}></c-s3>
</template>

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
  step1;
  step2;
  step3;
  resetAll() {
    this.step1 = false;
    this.step2 = false;
    this.step3 = false;
  }
  goToStep1() {
    this.resetAll();
    this.step1 = true;
  }
  goToStep2() {
    this.resetAll();
    this.step2 = true;
  }
  goToStep3() {
    this.resetAll();
    this.step3 = true;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.goToStep1();
  }
}


Hi @sfdxfox can you please elaborate what are 'onnext' and 'onprevious' here. Are they custom events passed from child to parent cmp's??

@HadiHusain Yes, they would be custom events.

to communicate between separated components, you can use LMS you can see this link.

Link only answers are discouraged on StackExchange, because links get faster obsolete than the texts they point at. Your answer would profit from a summary of the the text.
